# How to (properly) Deploy MongoDB on Kubernetes and Access it from Another Pod/Job?

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes

## 1. Problem Description

I'm trying to run a `MongoDB` `Deployment` + `Service` on `Kubernetes` where other `Pods`/`Jobs` or `Containers` could access it. So far I have apparently been successful at deploying it, however whenever I try to access it from within a `Job`, `Pod` or `Container`, I get (note that I'm using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` in order to access the host machine; and that my timeout is 30 seconds):

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 0.0.0.0:30001: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

## 2. Locally, it seems to work...

If I try to access it through a `Python` `CLI`, it *does* look like it works though:

```py
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='0.0.0.0', port=30001) # 'localhost' also works
>>> client.list_database_names()
['admin', 'config', 'local', 'test_db'] # 'test_db' is a db I had previously created
```

Should I use another host address when trying to access the `MongoDB` `service`? (If so, where does it show on `kubectl describe svc <service_name>`?)

## 3. `Deployment` and `Service` Configurations

My `MongoDB` `deployment` (adapted from [Nigel Poulton's Kubernetes Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072TS9ZQZ)) is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mymongodb-dep
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-mongo
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
```

And its `service` is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-svc
  labels:
    app: hello-mongo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    nodePort: 30001
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-mongo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your connectivity experience from within the `Kubernetes` cluster and from outside will be different.

From within the cluster you should reference the `MongoDB` `Pod` using `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local` rather than `0.0.0.0`. So, in your case, the `host` would end up being `hello-svc.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Also note that the `port` should be referenced as the one seen within the cluster and not the `NodePort`, which is used to access the cluster from outside. In your case, that would be `27017`.

Comment: In my case, it would be `hello-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` then? I've tried but still without success. And the port would still be `30001`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `namespace`s. Would I have to configure a new one or can I use the `default` one? If I indeed need to configure a new `namespace`, how would I easily do it in the aforementioned `YAML`s?

Comment: Yes `hello-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` should do it. It should be 27017 inside the cluster (interally it's the port value externally it's the nodeport value).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the help. Take a look at my edit, I think it improves the original answer with the discussion we've had here in the comments.